# Handle missing value in URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to find a way to avoid 500 server errors when a URL is broken and therefore either does not match or breaks an htaccess rule

For example,

```
https://www.acme.com/directory/url/123/123
```

This is a valid URL - but sometimes it comes through as

```
https://www.acme.com/directory/url//123
```

and this breaks and gives a 500 error.

In htaccess the redirect rule for this is

```
RewriteRule ^url/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) /directory/url.php?id=$1&request_id=$2 [L]
```

To try to combat this I have added:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . /errors/unexpected-error.php?url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The weird thing is this works on my local but not on live (on local it redirects to unexpected-error but on live in shows a 500 error) so I am not sure if this is a config thing on live or something I am not spotting in my htaccess.

Of course, we are trying to avoid this in the first place by making sure the email containing the URL can never be sent without both values etc but it relies on setup by the customer so we are getting through all possible scenarios

Is there another way of handling this?

Comment: You need to check the server's error log for details of the 500 error. The likely cause is that this is the result of a conflict with other directives that causes a rewrite-loop. Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file in your question.

Comment: Why not simply `^(.*)//+(.*)$` instead of `^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$` ?